# Keep constant button width while toggling the text. (No fixed width in CSS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a button component with a fixed padding and no fixed width.  This button is used in many places and I want the button to change width depending on the text displayed on the button.

I'm now trying to add a toggled spinner to the buttons so when a user clicks the button the text disappears and the spinner is displayed.  The problem I am running into is the button keeps resizing since the spinner is a different width than the text

```
export const Buttons = styled.button`
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
`
```

These are my current button styles.

Comment: You could consider keeping the text, but set a it to a transparent color.
Then, your spinner could be in absolute position, on top of the text

Comment: If you want the button width to be fixed, the you need to explicitly fix it by adding a width property to its styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want / can fix the button width, an option (maybe not the best, but it will work) you can try it to make the button text transparent while loading spinner is showing, and positioning that spinner absolutely inside the button. For instance, you could have something like:

```
<button>
   <span class="text">Press here</button>
   <span class="spinner"></spinner>
</button>

//CSS
.spinner { 
   //Your CSS styles here
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
   display: none;
 }
```

When you are not loading anythint, your `.spinner` should be hidden (display none, for instance); and when you want to show it, just change that display property; and make the `span.text` text transparent. Size will remain always the same, and you will have the effect you want.

```
button.loading .text {
   color: transparent;
}

button.loading .spinner {
   display: block;
}
```

This workaround should work, maybe not the best way, but one way :D